# Writing in ARM using RAW Mode

Tags: assembly, arm, cpu-architecture, low-level

So I currently have to write a Connect 4 program in ARM Assembly. However, I'm having a bit of a problem. My game won't allow me to add any chips above the bottom row. They just don't store into the array.

I've created the 2D array like so:

```
  .balign 4
board:
  .word 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

And I let the user input their row. However, it won't add above the very bottom.

Note: It's an array of integers. I use -1 to represent X chip, 1 to represent O chip, and 0 to represent empty ('-').

The following methods place the chip when the the input is column 1:

```
itsAOne:
push {lr}
mov r7, #100 @ignore this
mov r5, #0 @this is a check later, to know if we successfuly inserted something

ldr r4, addr_of_board @address of the board
mov r10, #140 @place 35 in the array X 4 bytes
bl oneLoop @loop below

b returns @return method

oneLoop:
push {lr}

CMP r5, #0 @if r5 is not 0, it means we inserted a chip, so we stop
BNE returns

ldr r5, [r4, r10] @we get the value of the bottom of the column
CMP r5, #0 @if it's empty
BLEQ oneInner @we do this method to place a chip

sub r10, r10, #28 @else we subtract 28 to go up a row
bl oneLoop @loop

b returns

oneInner:
push {lr}

mov r1, r9 @these lines are a test to figure out what is in r9
mov r0, #1
mov r2, #4
bl write
bl printNewLine


CMP r9, #1 @if its player 1, place an O
BLEQ playerO

CMP r9, #2 @if it's player 2, place an X
BLEQ playerX

str r5, [r4, r10] @store the new value in the board

b returns
```

If I narrow down my question however, I can't seem to print r9 out. When I do the code

```
mov r1, r9
mov r0, #1
mov r2, #4
bl write
bl printNewLine
```

Nothing prints except the newLine (which is \r\n since this is raw).

I've been tearing my hair out over this and cannot find the error. Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: show the source or api douementation of the "write" function

Comment: Most humans comment their code, especially assembly code.

Comment: I went ahead and commented it for you. Also the write documentation is here http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:write

Comment: Nothing in this code sets `r9`, but I'm going to guess it _doesn't_ contain a pointer to a string (since you're also comparing against `#1` and `#2`). Using a debugger would be more productive than uploading incomplete code dumps here, just sayin'